# Редактирование сайта с фронтенда по секретной ссылке админа

Tags: php, сессия

Пытаюсь создать на PHP самую простую flat-file CMS. Заметил идею, чтобы вместо ввода логина и пароля админ заходил по известной только ему и, соотвественно, секретной для других ссылке, например, `mysite.com/secretadminurl` и вводил в поле только пароль (т.е. поле для пароля появляется только при переходе по секретной ссылке). Это, насколько я понимаю, повышает безопасность и устраняет лишний шаг ввода логина, если сохранить себе секретную ссылку в закладках браузера. При этом авторизация через сессии.

Теперь возникла еще одна идея: предоставить админу возможность редактировать страницы сайта прямо с фронтенда. Т.е. после авторизации по секретной ссылке админ попадает на главную страницу фронтэнда, в самом верху сайта добавляется горизонтальное меню админ-панели на всю ширину окна и, если админ кликает по главному наполнению страницы, то он переходит в режим `contenteditable` и появляется еще маленькая панель wysiwyg-редактора. Аналогично при переходе на внутренние страницы сайта. При этом если админ в меню админ-панели, которое добавилось в самом верху сайта, выбирает, например, закладку "Плагины", а не "Страницы", тогда он переходит по ссылке `/secretadminurl&view=plugins` и ему уже открывается отдельная страница админ-панели со списком установленных в CMS плагинов.

Т.е. в главном index.php имеем, например:

```
$loggedIn = false;
if(isset($_SESSION['l'], $_SESSION['i']) && $_SESSION['i'] == __DIR__) {
    $loggedIn = true;
}
if($loggedIn == true && $userType == 'admin') {
    echo 'Admin-panel menu';
}
require_once __DIR__ . '/themes/active_theme/html.php';
```

Как лучше всё сделать, что нужно учесть и как сделать всё максимально безопасно?

Любые предложения и вопросы для уточнения приветствуются.

Comment: писать код для редактирования и отображения контента одновременно - идея не нова и используется в различных CMS. жирнейший минус - надо совмещать функционал обычного представления и функций редактирования. Это в принципе лишняя работf для сервера при генерации страниц, но также обернется  огромной радостью при редизайне проекта. отделяйте мух от слонов, на кой оно вам вперлось? плюс единственный - ты редактируешь сразу то что видишь. в остальном одни минусы.

Comment: По поводу ссылки, то секретный урл также часто используется. Однако используется с целью предотвращения попыток подбора паролей и т.п., (например [tag:prestashop]). Идея избавится от ввода логина потерпит фиаско на том шаге когда потребуется несколько пользователей-админов.

Comment: ну если у вас одностраничный сайт с единственным пользователем, то, конечно, пожалуйста, городите

Comment: потому что если несоклько юзеров шарят один логин, то считай это один юзер. В нормальной работе нужно знать какой конкретно пользователь что делал. То есть роль у них одна, логины разные. + могут быть и роли редакторов, менеджеров и т.п.

Comment: Нет, логины т.е. секретные страницы разные для каждого юзера, независимо от типа, просто админ-права предоставляются только юзерам с типом admin. И если нужно знать что кто делал здесь тоже проблемы не вижу

Comment: ну если каждому логину своя url то да. однако, пойди ее попробуй вспомни при необходимости. Данные форм браузеры вполне умеют сохранять лет 10 уже как. так что вводить логин обычно просто не ттребуется. тем более возможны всякие авторизации через соц сети и  т.п.

Comment: По поводу фронтэнда: почему "жирнейший минус - надо совмещать функционал представления и редактирования" ? Вроде бы наоборот кода меньше. Ведь один и тот же код выводит страницу как для посетителей так и для админа, просто для админа добавляется еще дополнительный код, как в моем примере

Comment: админки обычно универсальны и легко расширяемы. Вопрос в том, как вы хотите реализовать редактирование на фронте. Одно дело, когда контент начинает редактироваться прямо на своих местах, другое, когда открывается какая ни попап форма с полями для редактирования. Второе это по сути и есть отдельная админка. первое ничего кроме гемора не принесет, кода будет больше, он будет сложнее, его будет тяжело поддерживать.